# Writing greater and less than in excel syntax

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a sheet that from a particular cell multiple conditions have to be tested prior to it outputting the value, I want to be able to test criteria such as: less than 60 but greater than 25 in the same argument within an if(and( statement but am unsure how to represent this in the syntax. Thanks

Comment: No need to respond I have worked out a way of logically increasing the number if if and statements to cover each of my needed conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
=If(AND(A1>25, A1<60),"TRUE", "FALSE")
```

Cell A1 is being tested if it's between 25 and 60.  This equation would be in some other cell on the same sheet.